# How to access ViewModel using KendoUI Grid MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a view like that:

```
@model MySearchVM

//Filters
...
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Description)
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Letter)
...

//Grid
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyGridVM>()
    .Name("MyGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
       columns.Bound(p => p.Id).Hidden(true);
       columns.Bound(p => p.Description);
       columns.Bound(p => p.Letter);
    })
    .Groupable()
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Ajax()
          .Read(read => read.Action("_Read", "MyController"))
          .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id)))
)
```

My Controller :

```
public ActionResult _Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var list = repository.GetAll().Select(x => new MyGridVM()
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Description = x.Description,
        Letter = x.Letter,
    });

    return Json(list.ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

All works great... But I want to access my ViewModel in _Read action, so I can manually filter the result...

I tried to pass FormCollection, but only got that from : sort, page, pageSize, group and filter

How Can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: The `Read` handler for the Kendo UI Grid looks like it uses GET requests which means you will not have access to your View Model.  Access to your View Model in an action method comes from POSTing it and the MVC Model Binding creates it from the request data.  What you have to do is, what it looks like you are already doing, and retrieve it from your database.

Comment: But I want to filter the result with Description and Letter values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing will be send to the server automatically will be available inside the action method. What I can suggest you is to send whatever you need to that action method with the help of the [**data**](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-do-i-send-values-to-my-action-method-when-binding-the-grid?) function of the read configuration to send whatever you need.

e.g.

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax()
    .Read(read => read
        .Action("Read", "Home")
        .Data("additionalData")
    )
)
// -- removed for brevity
<script>
    function additionalData() {
        return {
            userID: 42,
            search: $("#search").val()
        };
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Is it the only way?
Can I do something like that: 

.Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Home", new { Model.Description }))

Comment: Basically there are several ways to send it to the server with the Ajax request of the Grid, but after all you need to send it (no magic here)

Comment: Yes you can do it like you shared.

Comment: Make sure that you named the parameter Description. Also check the network tab to see if you are sending anything at all to the server.

Comment: If I pass a string like that : .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Home", new { Description = "abc" }))  it works fine...
But using Model.Description pass alwys null...

Comment: Can you try to make it like .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Home", new { Description = Model.Description })). And did you try to add @(Model.Description) somewhere on the page to see if something is coming out of it at all?